# Optimization over 6 vectors

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Suppose I have an expression which depends on 6 unit vectors 
(3 dimensional). Hence, I need to optimize over 12 parameters (every vector contains 3 parameters, but one we can reduce by considering the norm =1). How to optimize any expression over 12 parameters?

My problem is to find those vectors which maximize the expression. Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: NMinimize (or NMaximize)?

Comment: As mentioned above, I want to use 6 unit vectors. So 2 parameters per vector -> let's say "a" and "b", then they both can take values [-1,1] but when a = 1 or -1, b has to be 0. How to use all these conditions? Any idea?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on the objective function you're maximizing? Any structure present might suggest an elegant geometric approach.

Comment: You can optimize over unit spheres (at least in v10): `Maximize[x1 + y1^3 + x2^2 - z2, {{x1, y1, z1} \[Element] Sphere[], {x2, y2, z2} \[Element] Sphere[]}] // FullSimplify`. In practice, you probably need to use `NMaximize`.